# Could AMP's version of a webpage's URL affect the traffic of the original one?

Tags: seo, google, domains, amp

It seems that Google AMP is really important when designing a webpage.

Recently I've researched information about AMP, but still I'm confused.

Our company has a webpage `www.example.com`

And I have a questions before adding AMP.

(1) If I design two versions of this page, AMP and non-AMP, and mobile users will see the URL of our website is `https:// www.google.com/amp/example.com`, will this affect the traffic of the original one? (`https://example.com`), because the AMP version's URL has the `google.com` as the domain, and not `example.com`.

Comment: `Google Amp is really important when designing webpage`, not true. AMP is a perk, not an essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not affect the non-AMP traffic of your website. It's still your content and your traffic. If you have Google Analytics installed on AMP pages you will see the AMP traffic on your Google Analytics dashboard.

Simon Hayter, I beg your pardon but I must disagree with you. If your website is in the news publishing or blog segment, I dare to say that AMP pages are essential nowadays. Our clients on those segments who invested on AMP pages have seen a 30% increase in average traffic in the last 6 months.